# Declaring custom completions to AUCTeX

Tags: auctex, completion

How do I declare custom completions for command arguments to AUCTeX?

I have a LaTeX package that defines a number of macros. I'm writing the Elisp style support manually as some of the TeX code is rather hairy. One of the macros is `\ref`-like, so in the style support file, I have

```
(TeX-add-symbols '("myref" TeX-arg-ref))
```

If I insert `\ref` or `\myref` with `TeX-insert-macro`, I get prompted for a label with completion. If I type `\ref{` and press `M-TAB` (`TeX-complete-symbol`), I get completions of labels. But if I type `\myref{` and press `M-TAB`, I only get the fallback to dictionary words.

How do I tell AUCTeX that the first argument of `\myref` should be completed as a label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add entries to `TeX-complete-list`. This isn't documented in the manual, but there are examples in the support files distributed with AUCTeX.

```
  (setq TeX-complete-list
        (append '(
                  ("\\\\myref{\\([^{}\n
\\%,]*\\)" 1 LaTeX-label-list "}")
                  ) TeX-complete-list))
```

Each element of `TeX-complete-list` is a list consisting of a regexp to complete after, e.g. the command name followed by an opening brace and the already-existing element content in a group, followed by either:

1. The number of the group that contains the text to be completed.
2. A function that is called with no arguments and returns a completion alist.
3. A string to add after a completion.

or:

1. A function of no arguments that is called to perform the completion.

Comment: In general `TeX-complete-symbol` doesn't receive as much love as `TeX-insert-macro`, it's good to see you gave this useful answer!